# ibm websphere 85 and db2 upgrade

Tags: jdbc, db2, websphere

We are upgrading from db2 v9.7 to v10.5. In websphere jdbc providers, is it necessarry to update db2jcc4.jar to new version? does any one has experience this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is this "issue" you are talking about? Is there any reason _not_ to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to update db2jcc4.jar to solve  DB2 JDBC driver issues.

Take a look at the following links about DB2 JDBC driver issues ;

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21358484

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21613493

Comment: I'll just add as a rule of thumb you always want the client to have the save version + fixpack jar file as the database server.